# Pandas: adding new column to existing Data Frame for grouping purposes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, bar-chart

I have a `pandas` Data Frame consisting of 2000 rows x 8 columns. I want to be able to group the first 4 columns together, as well as the other 4, but I can't figure out how. The purpose is to create a categorical bar plot, with colors assigned according to C1=C5, C2=C6, and so forth.

My Data Frame:

```
In[1]: df.head(5)
Out[1]: 

    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
0   15  37  17  10  8   11  19  86
1   39  84  11  5   5   13  9   11
2   10  20  30  51  74  62  56  58
3   88  2   1   3   9   6   0   17
4   17  17  32  24  91  45  63  48
```

Do you suggest adding another column such as `df['Gr']` or what else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html):

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 4 , df.columns])
print (df)
    a               b            
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
0  15  37  17  10   8  11  19  86
1  39  84  11   5   5  13   9  11
2  10  20  30  51  74  62  56  58
3  88   2   1   3   9   6   0  17
4  17  17  32  24  91  45  63  48
```

Then you can use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) and [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, a = plt.subplots(2,1)
df.xs('a', axis=1).plot.bar(ax=a[0])
df.xs('b', axis=1).plot.bar(ax=a[1])
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 4 , df.columns])
df.stack(0).T.plot.bar(rot='0', legend=False)

df.columns = ['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 4
df = df.T.plot.bar(rot='0')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, and how would you create the bar plot?

Comment: I add solution, please check it.

Comment: Thanks! What if the intended outcome was a categorical barplot with four bars on one side (xlabel=a) and four on the other (xlabel=b), instead of 5 categories?

Comment: ok, but `matplotlib` is not so easy for me, so give me a time

Comment: Sorry. Please take all the time you need.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand well. So problem is you need one graph, not 2? Or you need change `x-axis` to `c1-c8`, `y-axis no change` and legend to `0-4` ? Can you explain more? Thank you.

Comment: Yes I need one graph. Two categories (A and b), and four columns for each category.

Comment: So you need `df.T.plot.bar()`, but nicer labels in `axis-x` ?

Comment: ok I have 2 solution for you (I am not matplotlib expert, so sorry). Please check it and if need change something, I try tomorow (or post another question with tag `matplotlib`).  Now I have to go home.

Comment: Hi, here is a more detailed question on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774826/pandas-how-to-draw-a-bar-plot-with-two-categories-and-four-series-each

Answer (score 1):

use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :4], df.iloc[:, 4:]], axis=1, keys=['first4', 'second4'])
```

[image]

Comment: How would you create the bar plot from here?