# How to draw a bar plot with two categories and four series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have the following dataframe, where `pd.concat` has been used to group the columns:

```
    a               b            
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
0  15  37  17  10   8  11  19  86
1  39  84  11   5   5  13   9  11
2  10  20  30  51  74  62  56  58
3  88   2   1   3   9   6   0  17
4  17  17  32  24  91  45  63  48
```

Now I want to draw a bar plot where I only have two categories (`a` and `b`), and each category has four bars representing the average of each column. Columns C1 and C5 should have the same color, as should columns C2 and C6, and so forth.

**How can I do it with *df.plot.bar()?***

The plot should resemble the following image. Sorry for it being hand-drawn but it was very hard for me to find a relevant example:
[image]

**EDIT**

This is the header of my actual DataFrame:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8
0   34  34  34  34  6   40  13  26
1   19  19  19  19  5   27  12  15
2   100 100 100 100 0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   100 100 100 100 0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply perform `unstack` after calculating the `mean` of the `DF` to render the bar plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('white')

#color=0.75(grey)
df.mean().unstack().plot.bar(color=list('rbg')+['0.75'], rot=0, figsize=(8,8))
```

[image]

---

**Data:** (As per the edited post)

```
df
```

[image]

Prepare the multiindex `DF` by creating an extra column by repeating the labels according to the selections of columns(Here, 4).

```
df_multi_col = df.T.reset_index()
df_multi_col['labels'] = np.concatenate((np.repeat('A', 4), np.repeat('B', 4)))
df_multi_col.set_index(['labels', 'index'], inplace=True)
df_multi_col
```

[image]

```
df_multi_col.mean(1).unstack().plot.bar(color=list('rbg')+['0.75'], rot=0, figsize=(6,6), width=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `seaborn`

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

def r(df):
    return df.loc[df.name].reset_index(drop=True)

data = df.mean().groupby(level=0).apply(r) \
         .rename_axis(['grp', 'cat']).reset_index(name='mu')

ax = sns.barplot(x='grp', y='mu', hue='cat', data=data)

ax.legend_.remove()
for i, p in enumerate(ax.patches):
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x() + .05, height + 1, df.columns.levels[1][i])
```

[image]