# seaborn bar plot from dataframe with multiple columns and datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn, bar-chart

I have dataframe with two columns like this (with date as index) :

[image]

my goal is to plot bar with seaborn like this (with excel)  :

[image]

I followed the discussion from [seaborn multiple variables group bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505456/seaborn-multiple-variables-group-bar-plot)

I know that I must use melt, but when I put the following code the result is the index (date) disappear (replaced by number), and the dataframe structure changed like this :

```
# pd.melt(df, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B'])
premier_melt = pd.melt(final_mada_df,id_vars=["Confirmed"],value_vars = ["Recovered"])
```

[image]

how can we solve this kind of  problem to plot bar with seaborn correctly

---

I put the code below following the advice below :

```
# main dataframe 
  df2
       Recovered Confirmed
3/20/20   0          3
3/21/20   0          0
3/22/20   0          0
3/23/20   0          9
 
df2.stack()
```

out :

```
3/20/20  Recovered    0
         Confirmed    3
3/21/20  Recovered    0
         Confirmed    0
3/22/20  Recovered    0
                     ..
5/4/20   Confirmed    0
5/5/20   Recovered    2
         Confirmed    2
5/6/20   Recovered    0
         Confirmed    7
Length: 96, dtype: int64

df2.rename(columns={'level_1':'Status',0:'Values'})
```

out :

```
       Recovered Confirmed
3/20/20   0         3
3/21/20   0         0
3/22/20   0         0
3/23/20   0         9
3/24/20   0         5
```

but when I put the following code , there is an error :

```
# plot 
ax = sns.barplot(x=df2.index,y='Values',data=df2,hue='Status')

ValueError: Could not interpret input 'Values'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Use [`.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) or [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to transform the dataframe from a wide to long format, as shown below.

### Imports and Sample Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# optional graph format parameters
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16.0, 10.0)
plt.style.use('ggplot')

# data
np.random.seed(365)
data = {'Confirmed': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(25)],
        'date': pd.bdate_range(datetime.today(), freq='d', periods=25).tolist()}

# dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# add recovered
df['Recovered'] = df['Confirmed'].div(2)

| date                |   Confirmed |   Recovered |
|:--------------------|------------:|------------:|
| 2020-05-12 00:00:00 |           4 |         2   |
| 2020-05-13 00:00:00 |           1 |         0.5 |
| 2020-05-14 00:00:00 |           5 |         2.5 |
| 2020-05-15 00:00:00 |           1 |         0.5 |
| 2020-05-16 00:00:00 |           9 |         4.5 |

# verify datetime format and set index
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
```

### Transform DataFrame

#### Using `.stack`

- This transformation is required to get the desired plot from seaborn

```py
df1 = df.stack().reset_index().set_index('date').rename(columns={'level_1': 'Status', 0: 'Values'})
```

#### Using `.melt`

```py
df1 = df.melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='Status', value_name='Values')
```

#### Transformation Result

```py
               Status  Values
date                         
2022-06-24  Confirmed     2.0
2022-06-25  Confirmed     4.0
2022-06-26  Confirmed     1.0
2022-06-27  Confirmed     5.0
2022-06-28  Confirmed     2.0
```

### Seaborn plot

- Formatting the x-axis tick labels needs to use `df` not `df1`.  As can be seen above, each date repeats, so `df1.index.to_series()` will produce a list with repeating dates.

```py
ax = sns.barplot(x=df1.index, y='Values', data=df1, hue='Status')

# format the x-axis tick labels uses df, not df1
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))

# alternative use the following to format the labels
# _, labels = plt.xticks()
# labels = [label.get_text()[:10] for label in labels]
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(labels))

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

### Alternatively [`df.plot.bar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

- Produces the same graph as above, without the transformation to `df1`
- `df` has a datetime index, which is recognized as the x-axis, and all of the columns are plotted on the y-axis.

```py
ax = df.plot.bar()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(plt.FixedFormatter(df.index.to_series().dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))
plt.show()
```

[image]