# plot serveral pandas columns as "y" in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, bar-chart

I want to create barplot with seaborn that will display the mean value for three columns from pandas dataframe
My  dataframe is ismilar to this:

```
>>>name      treatment    weight    height   ind1
0  Miki      93A control  77.5      23.2     105.5
1  Lorense   75B high     35.1      25.1     57.3
2  Derek     93A high     74.3      26.4     94.5
3  Lily      24C medium   12.2      14.4     26.8
4  Tim       75B high     37.2      26.4     55.1
...
```

I want to get bar plot that has the treatments as x -axis, and the weight, height and ind1 as the bars. and on this to display the error.

I have tried to do it simply with seaborn, but it works to me only when I try to plot on variable, such as weight, hright or ind1, but does not let me add more than one "variable" :

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="treatments", y="weight", data=df)
```

(illustration of the results:):
[image]

I have tried to create list of variables like in matplotlib for the y :

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="Treat Name alias", y=["weight","height","ind1"], data=df)
```

but then I get the error messege:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

the problem is that I would like to have more than one columns as the y value. I have seen the catplot option but it seems that they grouping specific columns and not plotting each column as y value with the same x-axis.

My desired output will be **to have the treatment as x-axis, and then for eac treatment to have three bars, one for weight,one for height and one for the ind1**. And to have the std plot (the "black line" on the bars).

Comment: @anky that creates hige chart with long x axis that has the treatments repeating many times and no error appears. I would like to use te seaborn package in order to have the error easily.

Comment: got it: [seaborn multiple variables group bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49505456/seaborn-multiple-variables-group-bar-plot) this has been answered here, if you need something else, let me know and edit the question. For your question. All of the solution works.

Comment: bdw i actually meant this: `df.groupby("treatment",sort=False).mean().plot.bar()` :) didn't see the std requirement sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to reshape your dataframe

```py
df = df.melt(id_vars=['name', 'treatment'], var_name='measurement', value_name='mean')
```

Resulting in...

```
   name treatment measurement   mean
0   93A   control      weight   77.5
1   75B      high      weight   35.1
2   93A      high      weight   74.3
3   24C    medium      weight   12.2
4   75B      high      weight   37.2
5   93A   control      height   23.2
6   75B      high      height   25.1
7   93A      high      height   26.4
8   24C    medium      height   14.4
9   75B      high      height   26.4
10  93A   control        ind1  105.5
11  75B      high        ind1   57.3
12  93A      high        ind1   94.5
13  24C    medium        ind1   26.8
14  75B      high        ind1   55.1
```

Now when you plot it in seaborn you'll have multiple variables 'within' one column, so you can call it like this...

```py
g = sns.catplot(
    data=df, kind="bar",
    x="treatment", y="mean", hue="measurement",
    ci="sd", palette='colorblind', alpha=.6, height=6
)
```

This gives you...

[image: example result]